# How to Get Data From DB with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

I have a front-end website created as Angular project. (using node.js) I have created a "server.ts" file and connected to the my DB succesfully. Now I want to get data from my database and print some on dashboard. How can I get data ?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({

host: "myhost",
user: "myusername",
password: "mypassword"
});
con.connect(function(err){
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get data from the database in an Angular app. Angular is a front-end framework, it means that you angular application will be downloaded and executed in the user's browser. 
To access data from the database that is in the server side, you need a back-end application. You could do it from a node.js application with help of a framework like [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).
There is an example in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fNlrEDolko)

Comment: Not wrong, but not right either. Of course a frontend application can receive data from a backend... by using REST for example. The backend exposes some access points for the frontend to consume.

Comment: is it possible to load DB like sqlite from disk in frontend app? then use it? maybe with some service with predefined queries like 'getAllItems' fired on this loaded file?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create some sort of api for your front-end application to communicate with the backend server. A common option for this is [Express](https://expressjs.com/). This involves quite a lot of code, so if you want specific help I suggest putting together a stackblitz, alternatively you may be interested in the following example:

https://morioh.com/p/33d0377536a6/angular7-crud-with-nodejs-and-mysql-example

If you want a more complete solution, you could also look into implementing a tooling system such as [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)

Answer (score 0):

from lib [README](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction) on Github:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

you can use `.query()` for example to trigger requests and fetch data.

Comment: how to call .connect method in angular?